# Как в Matplotlib сделать функцию для автоматического построения графиков с заявленными параметрами

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, графика, matplotlib

Необходимо автоматизировать построение серии графиков в которой меняется только один столбец.

```
month_last_price = data.pivot_table(index='month', 
                                   values = 'last_price', 
                                   aggfunc = 'count').plot(grid=True, figsize=(12, 5))

day_last_price = data.pivot_table(index='weekday', 
                                   values = 'last_price', 
                                   aggfunc = 'count').plot(grid=True, figsize=(12, 5))
```

Как лучше сделать через функцию или через цикл?
Попытался вот так

```
def super_show(index_data, value_data):
    super_show.plot(index = index_data,  values = value_data, grid=True, figsize=(12, 5))
super_show('year', 'last_price')
plt.show()
```

Но пишет что

> AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'plot'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос:

```
def super_show(data, index, values, columns=None, aggfunc="count", 
               fill_value=0, dropna=True, figsize=(12, 5), grid=True, **kwargs):
    (data
     .pivot_table(index=index, values=values, columns=columns, 
                  aggfunc=aggfunc, fill_value=fill_value, dropna=dropna)
     .plot(figsize=figsize, grid=grid, **kwargs))
```

---

вызов:

```
super_show(data=data, index='year', values='last_price')
```

Comment: а как можно сделать через цикл тоже самое действие ?

Comment: @Anofelesoff, `_ = [super_show(data=data, index=idx, values='last_price') for idx in ['year', 'month', 'day']]` ?

Comment: я имел ввиду вместо функции применить [цикл вот тут](https://pastebin.com/DBmGxVby) попробовал но пишет ошибку

Comment: @Anofelesoff, думаю лучше задать новый вопрос с небольшим примером входных данных и того, что вы хотите получить на выходе